# Deleting with cascading in EF Code-First and self-referencing entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class Folder that contains Folders and Sets:

```
public class Folder
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public virtual int FolderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentFolderId")]
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentFolderId { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("FolderId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentFolderId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

}
```

To delete Folders I'm doing this:

```
private void InternalDeleteFolder(DbContext db, int folderId)
    {
        var folder = InternalGetFolder(db, folderId);

        foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders.ToList())
        {
            InternalDeleteFolder(db, subFolder.FolderId);
        }

        foreach (var set in folder.Sets.ToList())
        {
            InternalDeleteSet(db, set.SetId);
        }

        if (folder.ParentFolder != null)
        {
            folder.ParentFolder.Folders.Remove(folder);
            SaveChanges(db);
        }
        db.Folders.Remove(folder);
        SaveChanges(db);
    }
```

This is taking a very long time for folders with lots of data though - I have to make one call to the db per folder/set.  Is there a better way to handle this, perhaps with the fluent api in my db context?